# Dealer/Router for asynchronous client server?

Tags: zeromq

Using ZeroMQ, I am building a client/server application that requires asynchronous message - at some point my server might send 2 messages in a row and then the client sends 10, or continuous exchange of messages.

Does this qualify for use of the dealer/router setup or if this is not something ZeroMQ is setup for?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### ZeroMQ can out of question provide means for doing this,

yet, this is not the very case for using the original **`ROUTER/DEALER`** smart Scalable Formal Communication Pattern archetype.

Given an unspecified message ordering is required, may be fine to use **`PAIR/PAIR`** where any side may send whatever amount of messages, whenever it decides to ( there is no formal ordering pre-wired ).

Hope this helps.